# What API is there for selecting iTunes library location?

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes, ituneslibrary

How does one programatically set the iTunes library location on macOS to custom locations using e.g. C / Obj-C or Swift API?

Alternatively, environmental settings, such as modifying plists, using the `defaults` CLI tool, or similar approaches, are also OK for me.

Ordinarily, selecting a custom iTunes library location is done by launching iTunes while holding down the option key. I need to be able to do this in e.g. a unit testing environment / programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set it via the prefs.
This is how I access it.

```
-(void)loadITunesPrefLibraryPath {
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *userPref = [userDefaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.iTunes"];

id dataBaseLoc = [userPref objectForKey:@"Database Location"];
NSLog(@"%s dataBaseLoc is:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, dataBaseLoc);
NSLog(@"%s dataBaseLoc class is:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [dataBaseLoc class]);
NSData* dataBaseData = (NSData*)dataBaseLoc;
BOOL staleBook = NO;
NSError* bookError = nil;
NSURL* dataBaseURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:dataBaseData options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutMounting relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:&staleBook error:&bookError];
self.libExtDBfile = dataBaseURL;
}
```

Once you get the userPrefs for iTunes.
And create a BookMarkData from URL.
You might be able to set it via

```
[userPref setObject:newDataBaseLoc forKey:@"Database Location"];
```

also see next answer for possible ITLibrary framework private API access

Comment: Why was my other post deleted?